# How do I use the Print Module with a Custom Form Module?

Tags: 7

I have searched and searched but have not found a definitive answer or direction. I've installed the [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module (Printer, email and PDF) and have it successfully working when associated with content types.

My problem however, is making it work with custom forms. I have tried placing `print_insert_link()` in the form and it doesn't show up. I think all I'm missing is an example of `print_insert_link()` pointing to a custom form module. The path for the custom module I'm working with now is `glatfelter_forms/form_scorecard`.  How do I properly use `print_insert_link()`?  I'm using Drupal 7.23. This is my first post so please let me know if I can provide any additional detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration page of the [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module at `admin/config/user-interface/print`, there is a section **'Show link in system (non-content) pages'**.

If you select **Show on only the listed pages.** and enter the path of your form (`glatfelter_forms/form_scorecard`) in the textarea below, there will be a print link on that page.

Comment: I completely missed that. It worked perfectly! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.